# How to initialize and save data to 2d array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, proc

If I had a 2d array  with multiple c strings, how would I initialize the array without knowing how many c string will be added into that array.

I have tried to initialize like below but when I try to add a c string I get an error when compiling.
Error : explicit dimensions specification or initializer for an auto or static array.

```
static Char data[][100]; 

int main(){
  int i;
  char word[5];

  strcpy(word,"data");

  For(i=0; i < rows; i++){
    strcpy(data[i],word);
  }

}
```

So the array should hold for example

```
data[][100]= {"data","data"};
```

The row value depends on how many rows are retrieved from an sql so my problem is I want to somehow dynamically create the array to fit the size of the rows retrieved from the SQL.

Any help or information would be great.

Comment: `char word; strcpy(word,"data");` Hmmm, almost 100% Segmentation Fault chance.

Comment: When you say "SQL" do you mean to store a SQL query or to store the result obtained by one?

Comment: MikeCAt sry that was a mistake on my part. @Ludin I have a cursor which runs an exec SQL query and stores it. Then depending on the row count, I want to store it. So if 3 payments are retrieved for a member then it would add those 3 to the array.

Comment: I think you should get the 'Segmentation fault' Error and not your mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer to array and reallocation.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for realloc() */
#include <string.h> /* for strcpy() */

int rows = 100; /* for example */

static char (*data)[100] = NULL;

int main(){
  int i;
  char word[100]; /* allocate array, not a single char */

  strcpy(word,"data");

  for(i=0; i < rows; i++){
    char (*newData)[100] = realloc(data, sizeof(*data) * (i + 1));
    if (newData == NULL) { /* allocation error */
      free(data);
      return 1;
    }
    data = newData;
    strcpy(data[i],word);
  }

}
```

Comment: I shall give this a go. Thanks

Comment: Obviously this is very inefficient though, so it would be better to keep track of the number of items actually used and then realloc when running out of them. For example, start out with 100 `malloc`ated pointers, and then realloc by `prev_size*2` when running out of memory.

Comment: Oh and btw you are forgetting to actually allocate space for the individual strings here. You need `(*data)[i] = malloc(strlen(input)+1);`. And `strcpy(data[i],word);` is wrong... it's doing pointer arithmetic on whole arrays, not pointers.

Comment: @Lundin No, `(*data)[i] = malloc(strlen(input)+1);` is not needed and is harmful because it will break the first data (`(*data)[i]` is equivalent to `data[0][i]`), lead to memory leak, and may lead to out-of-bound write (if there are more than 100 rows). And `strcpy(data[i],word);` is not wrong if `word` contains valid and short enough string. Note that I am using pointer to array, not pointer to pointer.

Comment: Yes you are using a pointer to a one-dimensional array of characters, which is why you can't use pointer arithmetic `data[i]`. Pointer to array, unlike actual arrays, do not decay into a pointer to the first element. So my take is that you want to use this as some manner of "mangled" 2D array, since this is just an obfuscated way of writing `char* data = malloc(100);`, there's no obvious reason to use an array pointer here.

Comment: And regardless of the whole strange array pointer thing, there's really no excuse to call realloc repeatedly in a loop like this, and we should not teach newbies to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many strings there will be in advance, you either have to set a fixed maximum limit to the `static` array, or alternatively use dynamic allocation of an array of `char` pointers.

When using dynamic allocation, you can `malloc` a "pretty large number" at first, keep track of how many strings there are, and then `realloc` when you run out of space.

EDIT: pseudo-code example without error handling, free() etc

```
int main (void)
{
  size_t alloc_size = sizeof(char*[100]);
  char** data = malloc(alloc_size); 

  for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++){
    if(i > alloc_size)
    {
      alloc_size *= 2;
      data = realloc(data, alloc_size);
    }

    size_t str_size = strlen(input)+1;
    data[i] = malloc(str_size);
    memcpy(data[i], input, str_size);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.